# Exact Same Script Works On One Page But Not Another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building an iOS7 WebApp with a template that I found here:
http://c2prods.com/2013/cloning-the-ui-of-ios-7-with-html-css-and-javascript/

I have written some JavaScript/jQuery that fades a picture out and fades a toolbar in, toolbar first. I have a blank test page where I tested the script. It works perfectly. Then I copy and paste the EXACT SAME code into the real page and the jQuery never seems to load for whatever reason. It gives me an error saying the following:

Uncaught TypeError: Object #  has no method 'fadeOut'

The fading is supposed to occur after 3 seconds. The idea is that this is a splash screen.

Here is my JS/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
fadeAwaySplash();
navFadeIn();
//Insert More Functions Here
});

function fadeAwaySplash() {
    //setTimeout(function() {
    $("#splash-screen").fadeOut();
    //}, 3000);
}

function navFadeIn(){
    setTimeout(function() {
    $("nav").fadeIn();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Here is my CSS:

```
nav {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 49px;
text-align: center;
background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0.9);
background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(200, 199, 204), rgb(200, 199, 204) 50%, transparent 50%);
background-size: 100% 1px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top center;
z-index: 100;
display: none;
}

#splash-screen {
position: absolute;
z-index: 999999;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<img src="/img/ipadSplash.png" id="splash-screen">
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Emanuel

Comment: Do you have anything on your second page that might be overriding jQuery? Have you tried replacing the $s with jQuery to avoid this overriding?

Comment: Also I may recomment to wipe ot all cache and reload the page. Maybe some older jquery version is cached.

Comment: is <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> on all your pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great! scragar's answer worked! All I had to do is replace the $'s with "jQuery" (without the quotation marks). Although I had to replace the setTimeout with .delay(3000) Thanks!